# Mock a controller for unit test without any service reference C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am having a simple controller which needs to be unit tested not integration tested. I just need a way to mock so that I can verify if receive method is called. We already have test against Receive(), so no need to verify what is going inside that method.

My code looks like

```
public class MessageController : Controller
{       
    private readonly ConnectionDetail connectionDetail;

    private readonly QueueDetail queueDetail;

    public MessageController(IOptions<ConnectionDetail> connectionDetail, IOptions<QueueDetail> queueDetail)
    {
        this.connectionDetail = connectionDetail.Value;
        this.queueDetail = queueDetail.Value;
    }

    [HttpGet()]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var channel = CreateConnectionAndChannel(queueDetail);
            var message = channel.Receive();              
            var hbaseKey = new HbaseKey { Key = new Guid(message) };
            return Ok(hbaseKey);
        }
        catch
        {
            return StatusCode(500, "Exception occured while processing. Try again.");
        }
    }

    private IChannel CreateConnectionAndChannel(QueueDetail queueDetail)
    {
        var factory = new Factory();
        var adapter = factory.Connect(MessagingType.MQ, connectionDetail);          
        return adapter.BindQueue(queueDetail);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a `new Factory()` in there. In general, any code that contains `new` is not testable. You'll have to go and inject an `IFactoryFactory`, I'm afraid.

Comment: You should have `CreateConnectionAndChannel` functionality as part of some other class and that should be injected as a dependency to the controller. And unit tests should use mock of that along with other mocks to unit test controller

Comment: @CodeCaster - That's what I was thinking :(

Comment: @Developer Like Chetan suggested you should refactor that whole function out and have the controller depend on that

Comment: Interfaces are your friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor the `CreateConnectionAndChannel` function out into its own service

```
public interface IChannelProvider {
    IChannel CreateConnectionAndChannel();
}
```

and have controller explicitly depend on that service

```
public class MessageController : Controller {
    private readonly IChannelProvider channelProvider;

    public MessageController(IChannelProvider channelProvider) {
        this.channelProvider = channelProvider;
    }

    [HttpGet()]
    public IActionResult Get() {
        try {
            var channel = channelProvider.CreateConnectionAndChannel();
            var message = channel.Receive();              
            var hbaseKey = new HbaseKey { Key = new Guid(message) };
            return Ok(hbaseKey);
        } catch {
            return StatusCode(500, "Exception occured while processing. Try again.");
        }
    }    
}
```

So now only the `IChannelProvider` needs to be mocked to test the controller in isolation.

> I just need a way to mock so that I can verify if receive method is called.

```
public void Verify_Received_Called() {
    //Arrange
    var channel = new Mock<IChannel>();
    channel
        .Setup(_ => _.Receive())
        .Returns("My mock value here");

    var mockProvider = new Mock<IChannelProvider>();
    mockProvider.Setup(_ => _.CreateConnectionAndChannel())
        .Returns(channel.Object);

    var controller = new MessageController(mockProvider.Object);

    //Act
    var result = controller.Get();

    //Assert    
    channel.Verify(_ => _.Receive(), Times.AtLeastOnce);
}
```

The provider implementation could look like...

```
public class ChannelProvider : IChannelProvider {    
    private readonly ConnectionDetail connectionDetail;
    private readonly QueueDetail queueDetail;

    public ChannelProvider(IOptions<ConnectionDetail> connectionDetail, IOptions<QueueDetail> queueDetail) {
        this.connectionDetail = connectionDetail.Value;
        this.queueDetail = queueDetail.Value;
    }    

    public IChannel CreateConnectionAndChannel() {
        var factory = new Factory();
        var adapter = factory.Connect(MessagingType.MQ, connectionDetail);          
        return adapter.BindQueue(queueDetail);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you need to move your CreateConnectionAndChannel method to a separate dependency, for instance, ChannelFactory which implements IChannelFactory interface.

```
public interface IChannelFactory {
    IChannel CreateConnectionAndChannel(QueueDetail queueDetail);
}

public class ChannelFactory : IChannelFactory {
    public IChannel CreateConnectionAndChannel(QueueDetail queueDetail)
    {
        var factory = new Factory();
        var adapter = factory.Connect(MessagingType.MQ, connectionDetail);          
        return adapter.BindQueue(queueDetail);
    }
}

public class MessageController : Controller
{       
    private readonly ConnectionDetail connectionDetail;
    private readonly QueueDetail queueDetail;
    private readonly IChannelFactory channelFactory;

    public MessageController(IOptions<ConnectionDetail> connectionDetail, IOptions<QueueDetail> queueDetail, IChannelFactory channelFactory)
    {
        this.connectionDetail = connectionDetail.Value;
        this.queueDetail = queueDetail.Value;
        this.channelFactory = channelFactory;
    }

    [HttpGet()]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var channel = channelFactory.CreateConnectionAndChannel(queueDetail);
            var message = channel.Receive();              
            var hbaseKey = new HbaseKey { Key = new Guid(message) };
            return Ok(hbaseKey);
        }
        catch
        {
            return StatusCode(500, "Exception occured while processing. Try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

After that you can mock your controller in test (using Moq for example):

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestMessageController 
{
    [Test]
    public void TestGet() 
    {
        var channelMock = new Mock<IChannel>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        channelMock
            .Setup(c => c.Receive())
            .Returns(null);

        var channelFactoryMock = new Mock<IChannelFactory>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        channelFactory
            .Setup(cf => cf.CreateConnectionAndChannel(It.IsAny<IOptions<QueueDetail>>()))
            .Returns();

        var controller = new MessageController(null, null, channelFactoryMock.Object);
        controller.Get();
    }
}
```